GITHUB_OUTPUT is empty when accessed from subsequent job
I am new to GitHUB actions and trying to use the output of one job to another job
The following seems to be obvious but the output of job: get-diff results in null when accessed from job: test-json
  get-diff:
     runs-on: ubuntu-latest
     outputs:
       output1: "${{ steps.get-output.outputs.FILES_LIST }}"
     steps:
     - uses: actions/checkout@v3
       with:
         fetch-depth: 0
       id: get-output
     - run: |
         echo "Welcome to Job1"
         echo "FILES_LIST=30105002375689" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
                  
  test-json:
    needs: get-diff
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Test FILE_LIST variable
      run: echo "${{ needs.get-diff.outputs.output1 }}"

I enabled 'Debug' mode and confirmed that outputs.output1 is 'null'
Kindly need help to get rid of this issue as I am not sure what I am doing wrong

Does this also happen if you add them as env on your test-json job and then do echo $MY_ENV? As suggested by github docs here

id should be part of that particular step where you're setting the output param. Currently, it's part of your checkout step. Placing id correctly should fix your issue.

You have id assigned to wrong task
  get-diff:
     runs-on: ubuntu-latest
     outputs:
       output1: "${{ steps.get-output.outputs.FILES_LIST }}"
     steps:
     - uses: actions/checkout@v3
       with:
         fetch-depth: 0
     - id: get-output
       run: |
         echo "Welcome to Job1"
         echo "FILES_LIST=30105002375689" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
                  
  test-json:
    needs: get-diff
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Test FILE_LIST variable
      run: echo "${{ needs.get-diff.outputs.output1 }}"


I have not noticed that and fixed the issue.  Thanks a ton.
